# how to show div in other frame

Tags: javascript, css

I have a five frames inside frameset and inside third frame jsp, i have a div which loads the content dynamically as dropdown list. Problem is i need to increase the row size of the third frame to larger size to accommodate the dropdown values. If not, the dropdown div is overlapping with fourth frame and not showing any results

Below is the snippet

```
<frameset rows="0,0,28,*,21" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0" onunload="onUnload()">
<frame name="timeoutcontrol" id="MainEx_timeoutcontrol_0" src="/webtop1/wdk/timeoutcontrol.jsp?Reload=1362290081162&amp;__dmfFrameId=MainEx_timeoutcontrol_0&amp;__dmfClientId=1362290080503" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
<frame name="residentucfinvoker" id="MainEx_residentucfinvoker_0" src="/webtop1/component/residentucfinvoker?Reload=1362290081162&amp;__dmfFrameId=MainEx_residentucfinvoker_0&amp;__dmfClientId=1362290080503" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
<frame name="titlebar" id="MainEx_titlebar_0" src="/webtop1/component/titlebar?Reload=1362290081162&amp;__dmfFrameId=MainEx_titlebar_0&amp;__dmfClientId=1362290080503" title="Title Bar Documentum Webtop" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
<frame name="view" id="MainEx_view_0" src="/webtop1/webtop/classic/classic.jsp?Reload=1362290081162&amp;__dmfFrameId=MainEx_view_0&amp;__dmfClientId=1362290080503" title="Classic View. Use column header links to sort files" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
<frame name="messagebar" id="MainEx_messagebar_0" src="/webtop1/component/messagebar?Reload=1362290081162&amp;__dmfFrameId=MainEx_messagebar_0&amp;__dmfClientId=1362290080503" title="Message Bar. Location of success and failure messages." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
</frameset>
```

Is there any way to show the div dropdown values in fourth frame? Please advise

Comment: `<frameset>` long time no see.

Comment: Stop using frames. Problem solved. Frames are deprecated in HTML5 anyways.

Comment: Can you please advise any alternate to frames.

Comment: "anything else". Modern HTML+JS means you can load content into any element you want on the page, without reloading the page. Fetch your data using an XmlHTTPRequest object, and once the data's there, just load it into wherever you need it. Spend some time on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials, it'll be worth it for you.